# pdf file with more than 1 page is not displaying in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am accessing the pdf file with more than 1 page in base64 and displaying using the iframe. Below is my code to display the pdf file in iframe

```
<div style="padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;height: 100%;width: 100%">
            <iframe ng-if="fileExtension == 'pdf'" src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{attachment}}" style="height: 100%;width: 100%" >
            </iframe>
        </div>
```

The iframe is coming blank for pdf file with more than 1 page. Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't use object ?? /

Comment: <object ng-if="fileExtension == 'pdf'" data="data:application/pdf;base64,{{attachment}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%;padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px">
     </object>
I tried above code it did not worked for me even pdf file only.

Answer (score 0):

Modify code

```
<iframe ng-if="fileExtension == 'pdf'" src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{attachment}}" style="height: 100%;width: 100%" scrolling="auto">
            </iframe>
```